# A finite non abelian simple group is generated by two elements

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, simple-groups, finitely-generated

I found on the Internet ([here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~germoni/agreg/generatrices.pdf) if you speak French) without any proof nor reference the following result.

> Let $G$ be a non abelian simple group. Then $G$ is generated by a pair of elements.

In other words, there exists $(g_1,g_2)\in G^2$ such that $G=\langle g_1,g_2\rangle$.

---

How someone would prove such a result? Do you have any references where this is done? Is it a known fact (I have found nothing on the Internet)?

Comment: As far as I recall, this is one of those "simple" facts that are only known by virtue of the classification.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft it would be a fascinating claim to have a more direct proof for, though. I wonder if the number of generators can be proved to be below some other limit without using the classification of all groups.

Comment: [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements/59300#59300) is a link containing some discussion of the point and several references.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for you link, a lot of informations there !

Comment: It is proved in a 1962 [RobertSteinberg's article](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1962-018-0) in the *Canadian Journal of Mathematics*.

Comment: Googling your title gives a lot of literature, so i wonder why you said "I have found nothing on the Internet".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Because I didn't Googled it in English... (my bad)

Comment: @Bernard Steinberg's article only covers the finite simple groups that were known in 1962.

Comment: Really? I didn't read it, just looked at the presentation of the results. Maybe I read too hastlily.